# Linear programming with $XX^T=Identity$ constraint

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-system

I have the following system of equations

$$X R a - c_1 = 0$$
$$X a - c_2 = 0$$
$$X X^T=Identity$$

where $X\in\mathbb{R}^{3x3}$, $a,c_1,c_2\in\mathbb{R}^{3x1}$, $R\in\mathbb{R}^{3,3}$ is a rotation matrix.
For some $a,R,c_1,c_2$ the system has two possible $X$'s as a solution. In cases where there is no solution I want to find an $X$ which minimizes the "error" while maintaining that $XX^T=Identity$. How can this be done?

Would knowing the following help?
$$a = (0,0,-1)$$
$$|c_1|=1$$
$$|c_2|=1$$
$$X \text{ is a rotation matrix}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition $XX^T = I$ means $X$ is [orthogonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix).  So if the system has no solution, you would like to project an approximate solution (where $X$ is nearly orthogonal) onto its "orthogonal part", which is the "[Orthogonal Procrustes problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_Procrustes_problem)".  The solution method is described there.  Summarizing,
let $(Ra|a)$ be the $3 \times 2$ matrix whose first colument is $Ra$ and whose second column is $a$ and similarly for $(c_1|c_2)$.  If we were to write $X(Ra|a) - (c_1|c_2) = 0_{3 \times 2}$, we would exactly capture your first two constraints.  Instead, we will minimize this expression relative to the [Frobenius norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_norm#Frobenius_norm), which here is equivalent to the Euclidean matrix norm (the square root of the sum of the square of each of the six components).
\begin{align*}
\text{minimize } &||X \left( Ra \middle| a \right) - \left( c_1 \middle| c_2 \right) ||_F \\
\text{subject to } &XX^T = I
\end{align*}

Compute the [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) of $(c_1 | c_2)(Ra|a)^T$.
$$  (c_1|c_2)(Ra|a)^T = U \Sigma V^T  $$
then the projection of the solution onto the orthogonal component is
$$  X = UV^T  \text{.}  $$

(I've never actually implemented this algorithm, so a typo' or missing "T"ranspose in the above might slip past me.  If you find such a thing, I'm happy to fix it.)